# elmah throws a signal, difference with real exception when I look at the log

Tags: c#, exception, elmah

When I throw a signal to Elmah, it catches it, then I can find the exception via Elmah.axd page, my questions is, on the elmah.axd page, can I tell if the exception is from a signal or a really exception there, from the log?

Comment: What are you calling a signal? There's no such thing in .NET.

Comment: He's talking about Elmah and it's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to sort these is to create a custom exception.  We use one called "LogMessageException".  Whenever we are just signaling some logging information we use this.

That way we can filter out the logging noise from the real exceptions.

**update with sample class and call:**

```
public class LogMessageException : Exception {
    private LogMessageException() : base() {
    } // privatizing original constructor

    public LogMessageException( String message ) : base(message) {
    } // 

} // class::LogMessageException
```

**Sample Call**

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new LogMessageException("Say something here"));
```

Comment: Chris is correct, this would be the the best way to handle it, IMO. Either way, you'll still need to "filter" for it in one of the overrides you can put in the Global file. Chris, care to share that code for your custom exception and how you're using it?